# Remove space without using string method trim

Tags: javascript, function, trim

**How can I remove all the left space without removing between & the right space of the string? And also when I changed the value of str the result will be the same. Only the left space will be removed.**

```
function trimLeftSpace() {
    var str = "   Angry Bird   ";
    var splitTrim = str.split('');
    var trimStr = "";
    for (var index = 0; index < splitTrim.length; index++) { //trim left space
        if(splitTrim[index] != " ") {
            trimStr += str[index];
        }
    }
    return trimStr;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current solution creates a new string which contains all the non-space characters of the original string, you need to stop looking for spaces as soon as you find a non-space character. Here is an example:

```js
function trimLeftSpace(str) {
    var doneTrimming = false
    var ret = ""
    for (var index = 0; index < str.length; index++) {
        if(str[index] !== ' '){
            doneTrimming = true
        }
        if(doneTrimming){
            ret += str[index]
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

var result = trimLeftSpace("   Angry Bird   ");
console.log("|"+result+"|");
```

Comment: how about I want to remove right space? This code helped me a lot!

Comment: @LizQuenUpdate You can use the same code, you just need to reverse the original string before you run it then, when it is done, reverse the result.

Comment: @LizQuenUpdate Actually, it will be much easier to loop the original string from end to start and add the characters to the start of the result. For example: `for (var index = str.length - 1; index >= 0; index--)` and `ret = str[index] + ret`

Answer (score 2):

To trim the beginning of the string, use a simple [**`regex`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to replace the whitespaces in the beginning of the string:

```js
var str = "   Angry Bird   ";

function trimLeftSpace(str) {
  return str.replace(/^\s+/, '');
}

console.log('"' + trimLeftSpace(str) + '"');
```

Or just use [**`.trimStart()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimStart):

```js
var str = "   Angry Bird   ";

function trimLeftSpace(str) {
  return str.trimStart();
}

console.log('"' + trimLeftSpace(str) + '"');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try a regex replacement:

```js
var str = "   Angry Bird   ";
str = str.replace( new RegExp("^\\s+", "gm"),"");
console.log('"' + str + '"');
```

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes, I hear this often about `RegExp`.  Sadly, many highly viewed SO questions still promote it.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all whitespace on the left of the string:

```js
function trimLeftSpace(str) {
  var result = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(str[i] != " ") {
      return str.slice(i);
      break;
    } else {
      result += str[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(trimLeftSpace("   Angry Birds   Angry Birds"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function trimLeftSpace(str) {
    return str.replace(/\s+$/, '')
}

var result = trimLeftSpace("   Angry Bird   ");
console.log("|"+result+"|");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a function instead of regex solutions from the other answers, then make a function that looks for the first non-space character, then use `slice` to cut only the part of the string that's after it:

```js
function customTrim(str) {
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(str.charAt(i) !== " ") {
      return str.slice(i);
    }
  }
}

var res = customTrim("    Snake Shot    ");
console.log('"' + res + '"');
```

**Notes:**

- This only looks for spaces `' '`. If you want to look for tabs `'\t'`, newlines `'\n'`, ... then just add them to the `if` test (sperate them with `&&`).
- If an empty or space-only strings are passed, then `undefined` is returned, if you don't want that then just return an empty string at the bottom of the function to make it the default return value.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a regex replacement:

```js
   let variable = "hello world";
   let removeRegex = /^\s+|\s+$/g;
   let removeSpace = variable.replace(removeRegex,"");
   console.log(removeSpace);
```